# remove header and footer in word document in c#

Tags: c#, ms-word

Please help to remove a header and footer from the word document and change the font and save the doc.

Here is my code done only for change of font.

```
var application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
var doc = application.Documents.Open("word doc file here");
object start = doc.Content.Start;
object end = doc.Content.End;
Word.Range rng = doc.Range(ref start, ref end);
rng.Font.Name = "Times New Roman";
rng.Select();
doc.Save();
doc.Close();
```

Comment: `SeekView` then `MoveRight` then `Delete`.

Comment: JaYMee, Can you please elaborate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the code you show us works for you as far as changing the font and saving the document.

The following snippet shows two alternatives for changing the font. I used the font color to make things more obvious. The first changes the base style that underlies most of the font formatting you'll find in Word; the second is basically what you have - applying the formatting as if you'd select the body of the document and format it. The difference in my code is that it uses `Document.Content` which returns the `Range` for the main body of the document without needing to specify start and end values.

The snippet also demonstrates how to access a document's default Header and Footer. Note that Word documents can be extremely complex, with multiple `Section` objects, and each section object can have a "normal" header and footers as well as optionally a different header and footer for the first page. This snippet assumes the document has but the one section, and no different first page.

```
Word.HeaderFooter hdr = doc.Sections[1].Headers[Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary];
hdr.Range.Delete();
Word.HeaderFooter ftr = doc.Sections[1].Footers[Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary];
ftr.Range.Delete();
doc.Styles[Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleNormal].Font.ColorIndex = Word.WdColorIndex.wdBlue;
doc.Content.Font.ColorIndex = Word.WdColorIndex.wdDarkRed;
```